# Light direction not being calculated correctly

Tags: 2d, glsl, lighting, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to implement deferred lighting in my game, and have run into an issue with normals.

[image: bad lighting]

The image above shows the lighting being applied to a tile map. The yellow shade represents the direction of the light at that pixel. The character has a green normal so when he is below the light as he is in the screenshot, he doesn't get lit. I was working through the problem of the character always being lit, and it seems to be because the light direction isn't calcualted correctly. I expect the light direction color to be a rainbow of colors, however the yellow means that the light is always point down X and Y axis instead of radiating out in a circle. I'm certain that worldPos is coming out correct because the diffuse/normal colors are being displayed correctly.

Fragment shader for the light:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;
uniform sampler2D normalsTexture;
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 outColor;

void main(void) {
    vec2 resolution = vec2(200, 200);
    float distance = length(vec3((TexCoords*resolution) - (resolution / 2),
                                0.0));
    float constantAttenuation = 1.0;
    float linearAttenuation = 0.1;
    float quadradicAttenuation = 0.01;

    float attenuation = 1.0 / (constantAttenuation +
    (linearAttenuation*distance) + (quadradicAttenuation*distance*distance));

    vec3 worldPos = gl_FragCoord.xyz / vec3(1024, 768, 1.0);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(50,50,10) - worldPos);

    float diffuseFact = dot(normalize(texture2D(normalsTexture, worldPos.xy).rgb), lightDir);

    vec4 diffuse = vec4(0.0);

    if(diffuseFact > 0.0) {
        diffuse = vec4(texture2D(normalsTexture, worldPos.xy).rgb, 1.0);
        diffuse = diffuse * diffuseFact * 10;
    }

    outColor = vec4(lightDir, 0.5) + (diffuse*attenuation);
}
```

Comment: Two things pop out at me: Attenuation is usually relative to the light position, but here you're using `distance`, which is simply based on the screen coordinate of the pixel. Second, what's the format of `normalsTexture`? I'd expect you to have encoded normals (maybe `(normal vector) * 0.5 + (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`?) and then decode them in this shader (i.e. `(encoded normal) * 2 - (1, 1, 1)`).

Comment: I'm rending the light out via a rectangle, and calculating the light from the center of it. This is so I don't have to run the fragment shader on every pixel on the screen for every light. The format of normalsTexture is a RGB texture. Right now I'm just assigning specific colors to the tile map and the sprite for testing. The sprite is full green and the map is full white in the screenshot

Comment: I would advise against using magic numbers in your transformation from window-space (`gl_FragCoord.xyzw`) to world-space. You are also neglecting to consider the division by `w` that occurs between clip-space and window-space. Window-space `w` is `1.0/clip_w` and this is done so that you can properly undo the original division by `w` to reverse the transformation.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Definitely, I'll be replacing the magic numbers with varibles once I get around to cleaning up the code. Right now I just want to get it functioning. I'm not certain what you mean by your second point. Since I'm using orthographic projection, w isn't included in the calculation

Comment: Your question mentions nothing about what kind of projection you are using. To handle the general case, you must always divide by `w`. It *may be* a no-op in an orthographic projection, however, even then there are situations where `w` is not **1.0**; the only thing an orthographic projection guarantees is that `w` does not vary with distance down the z-axis. Speaking of which, `worldPos.z` is always between **0.0** and **1.0** assuming default depth range. You are computing the direction from `(50,50,10)` to a location that is `(...,...,[0,1])`; `lightDir` will *always* point down the Z-axis.

Comment: And you need to multiply `lightDir` by `0.5` and add `0.5` in order to properly visualize it as a color. Right now you are not handling situations where any of the coordinates are negative properly.

Comment: Ah, so your light rectangle is 200 by 200, and `distance` is from the center of that? In that case, I believe that `lightDir` should be also be based on the center of that rectangle and not world coordinates. Probably `lightDir = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.1) - vec3(TexCoords, 0.0)`.

Comment: @VictorT. Yes, that seems to have worked! I feel so dumb. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept that. Result: http://i.imgur.com/SwNwzzH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At rcapote's suggestion, here's my answer as an answer:

Ah, so your light rectangle is 200 by 200, and distance is from the center of that? In that case, I believe that lightDir should be also be based on the center of that rectangle and not world coordinates. Probably lightDir = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.1) - vec3(TexCoords, 0.0).

Glad I could help!